# How to have a sentiment score for a document in Quanteda?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, quanteda

I am new in sentiment analysis. [Quanteda examples](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/advanced-operations/targeted-dictionary-analysis/) show how to output numbers of positive and negative words. I tested some documents. It output below:

**Case 1**

```
document    negative    positive
file1   28  28
file2   98  71
file3   28  22
file4   37  39
file5   7   36
```

or below

**Case 2**

```
document    negative    positive    neg_positive    neg_negative
file1   28  28  0   1
file2   98  71  0   0
file3   28  22  1   0
file4   37  39  0   1
file5   7   36  0   1
```

Can you let me know how to have scores for file1 .. file5 in both cases? Is that

(#positive - #negative) / #all in case 1 file2， （71-98）/(71+98)=-27/169= - 0.15 ?

what about case 2?

Thanks a lot.

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider `neg_positive` as `negative`, and `neg_negative` as positive, then you could create your index by combining the pairs of columns.  This is plausible because the "neg positive" for instance contains sequences such as "not good".

```
(rowSums(object[, c("negative", "neg_positive")]) -
    rowSums(object[, c("positive", "neg_negative")])) / rowSums(object) * 100
```

Another (better) measure is the logit scale described in 
2011. William Lowe, Kenneth Benoit, Slava Mikhaylov, and Michael Laver. "[Scaling Policy Preferences From Coded Political Texts.](https://kenbenoit.net/pdfs/Loweetal_2010_LSQ.pdf)" Legislative Studies Quarterly 26(1, Feb): 123-155.  This is the log(positive/negative) or

```
log( rowSums(object[, c("positive", "neg_negative")]) /
     rowSums(object[, c("negative", "neg_positive")]) )
```